# I want to clear local storage when i close either all my tabs(on last tab close) or on browser close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

can you all suggest **some approaches** by which i can clear local storage on last tab close and on browser close..

I used local storage and session storage to maintain a array in localstorage of sessions open and close and when the array is empty i clear Local Storage. but it is not working on the condition when user shutdown its pc without closing its browser or tab.

my code...

```
@HostListener('window:load', ['$event'])
  loadHandler(event: Event) {
    let hash = 'tab_' + formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd-hh:mm:ss:ms', 'en');
    sessionStorage.setItem('TabHash', hash);
    let tabs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TabsOpen')) || [];
    console.log(tabs);
    tabs.push(hash);
    localStorage.setItem('TabsOpen', JSON.stringify(tabs));
  }
 
  @HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
  beforeunloadHandler(event: Event) {
    let hash = sessionStorage.getItem('TabHash');
    let tabs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TabsOpen')) || [];
    tabs.pop();
    localStorage.setItem('TabsOpen', JSON.stringify(tabs));
 
    setTimeout(() => {
      let left_tabs_Open = localStorage.getItem('TabsOpen');
      if (left_tabs_Open == '[]') {
        window.localStorage.clear();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: look at the `beforeunload` event

Comment: Check out this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

Comment: tried beforeunload but has the same issue when you close browser by using  task manager or restarting your computer it doesnot delete the local storage

Comment: _"but has the same issue when you close browser by using task manager"_ - you can not expect to be able to execute any custom code any more, when the user simply _kills_ the whole browser task.

Comment: One more reason could be that you are performing an asynchronous action (wrapped in `setTimeout`). When the computer is shut down, the `unload` event listener is executed, but immediately afterwards the browser is closed and the code inside `setTimeout` is not executed.

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes) clearly state that the event is not fired reliably, you should not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

export class YourComponent {

  @HostListener('window:load', ['$event'])
  loadHandler(event: Event) {
    let hash = 'tab_' + formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd-hh:mm:ss:ms', 'en');
    sessionStorage.setItem('TabHash', hash);
    let tabs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TabsOpen')) || [];
    tabs.push(hash);
    localStorage.setItem('TabsOpen', JSON.stringify(tabs));
  }
 
  @HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
  beforeunloadHandler(event: Event) {
    let hash = sessionStorage.getItem('TabHash');
    let tabs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('TabsOpen')) || [];
    let index = tabs.indexOf(hash);
    if (index !== -1) {
      tabs.splice(index, 1); // Remove the hash from the array
      localStorage.setItem('TabsOpen', JSON.stringify(tabs));
    }
 
    // Check if there are no more tabs open and clear local storage
    if (tabs.length === 0) {
      localStorage.clear();
    }
  }

}
```

This fixes the issue with removing the correct hash from the TabsOpen array and removes the unnecessary setTimeout. It should work correctly to track open tabs and clear the local storage when all tabs are closed.

Comment: try closing browser using task manager / restarting your pc while tabs are open then this approach will not work untill you manually clear local storage

Comment: used setTimeout becouse when you refresh your last tab,  array will be empty for a moment and due to synchronised code it will delete your local storage..

Comment: To address this issue, you might need to consider alternative approaches outside the browser environment, such as server-side tracking or synchronization mechanisms. These approaches could involve periodically syncing session information with a server, so even if the browser is closed abruptly, the server can still maintain some state information about the session. However, implementing such solutions would depend on your specific application requirements and infrastructure setup.

Comment: thank you and looking for something that can be applied